# Limiting SQL Server2008 Query execution

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In MySQL if I have multiple queries on one page and I end each query with a ; this will prevent the next query from being ran (accidentally ran). this ensures that only that query is ran.

Is there a similar feature in SQLServer2008? So, If I have multiple queries on one page, is there a character or operator that can be added at the end of a query that stops the query execution, so only that query is ran?

I understand typically only the highlighted query will run, but I have seen the whole page get executed *(almost always by some mishap)* so I was looking for a way to protect/prevent any mishaps from happening.

EDIT: I am using SQL Server Management Studio (new query page)

thanks

Comment: What is a page in this context?  If you are using specific tools or utilities to execute your queries you need to identify them for a question like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various ways to do this.  Some methods I've used before are:

Use of `RETURN`:

```
 Select * From Table Where Foo = 'Bar'
 Return 
 Delete Table Where Foo = 'Bar'
```

`RETURN` will end the batch at that point, making it so the first query is run, but not the second.

Use of `NOEXEC`:

```
Set NoExec Off
Select * From Table Where Foo = 'Bar'

Set NoExec On
Delete Table Where Foo = 'Bar'
```

`NOEXEC` will disable the execution of all sql statements while it is active.

Some good old-fashioned commenting:

```
Select * From Table Where Foo = 'Bar'
--Delete Table Where Foo = 'Bar'
```

There are other things you can try using (such as `RAISERROR`), but in general, the best prevention is to separate your scripts into different files when possible, and to be mindful of what you're executing.  Either by way of highlighting, or reviewing the file before you press <kbd>F5</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you could place a 
     `RAISERROR('Oops', 18, 1)` 
between each query.     This will halt execution after the first (highlighted) query is run.